# Entity Framework Core remove-migration problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, rollback

I have some changes to rescaffold my tables and create a migration named `X`. I try to apply X via update-migration but I have an exception about some of default data. My `X` migration is not in `__EFMigrationHistory` table because of the exception. However, when I run `remove-migration` command to remove `X` migration, dotnet try to run `Down` function in `X`. I couldn't understand why this happened. 
I want to use `remove-migration` because to edit ModelSnapshot.cs file is hard manually.
Is there anyone who knows the reason?

Comment: Can you try running update-database Your_Last_Good_Migration, before running remove-migration command?

Comment: @Wijitha I did but it didn't work. X migration already haven't applied on database so update-database -migration [the-last-good-migration] hasn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. If the migration has a script related `HasData` function (`InsertData()`, `UpdateData()` or `DeleteData()`, that causes a trouble when you want to run remove-migration. I uncommented those lines and removed the last migration successfully.